# How to show particular modal if two modals are used in layout blade, suppose form is validated and when it return with errors

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-8

I have two modals (login and register ) in **layout.blade**
and I have included it in **index.blade**  @include('layout')

I am using this code to identify the modal i want but it doen't seems to be working

```
<p id="check_modal_type"></p>
```

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

function loginORregister(login_or_register){
    if(login_or_register=='login'){
        document.getElementById('check_modal_type').innerHTML = 'login';
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById('check_modal_type').innerHTML = 'register';
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    //$('#signupModal').modal('show');
    alert(abc);
            @if (count($errors) > 0)
                if(document.getElementById('check_modal_type').innerHTML =='register'){
                $('#signupModal').modal('show');
                }
                if(document.getElementById('check_modal_type').innerHTML =='login'){
                $('#loginModal').modal('show');
                }
            @endif
        });
    </script>
```

i am calling on **onclick="loginORregister('login');"** on submit button of form to change innerHTML
whenever respose comes with error the value changed by javascript resets... :(

If you have any idea how to achieve this or simply how I can know whick modal have to show when response come in specific modal

Thankyou guys in advance.

Comment: You are showing the modal on page load, Need  more clarification on your question to know what you wish to achieve. If you want to display modal on page load either you need to set the static value of `check_modal_type` initially `(before the modal('show')` ) or you need to pass value from php side

Comment: Why do you want to use authentication in modals ? If you include these 2 modals in your layout , all the future pages will also have these modals. I think it is easier to have 2 separate pages.

Comment: modals are not shown on load they shown when login or register button are pressed

Comment: I think using php variable it can be done